# 2005 Canadian Computer Competition(CCC) S1:Snow Calls. I don't know what is wrong with my code?

Tags: java

I'm having trouble debugging the code I have for this question. Can anybody tell or help me debug this program and tell me what the problems are just for future references? Thank you for your time.
Link to question: [CCC S1: Snow Calls](http://wcipeg.com/problem/ccc05s1)
My code for this question down below.
Code is written in Java.

```
package snowcalls1;
import java.util.*;
public class SnowCalls1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int l;
        l = input.nextInt();
        String pre [] = new String [l];
        for (int i = 0;i<l;i++){
            pre[i] = input.nextLine();
        }
        String out [] = new String [l];
        for (int i = 0;i<l;i++){
              out[i] = "";
          }
        for (int i = 0;i<l;i++){
            for (int b = 0;b<=12;b++){
                if (pre[i].substring(b,b)== "1")out[i] = out[i] + "1";               
                if (pre[i].substring(b,b) == "2"||pre[i].substring(b,b) == "A"||pre[i].substring(b,b) == "B"||pre[i].substring(b,b) == "C")out[i] = out[i] + "2";
                if (pre[i].substring(b,b) == "3"||pre[i].substring(b,b) == "D"||pre[i].substring(b,b) == "E"||pre[i].substring(b,b) == "F")out[i] = out[i] + "3";
                if (pre[i].substring(b,b) == "4"||pre[i].substring(b,b) == "G"||pre[i].substring(b,b) == "H"||pre[i].substring(b,b) == "I")out[i] = out[i] + "4";
                if (pre[i].substring(b,b) == "5"||pre[i].substring(b,b) == "J"||pre[i].substring(b,b) == "K"||pre[i].substring(b,b) == "L")out[i] = out[i] + "5";
                if (pre[i].substring(b,b) == "6"||pre[i].substring(b,b) == "M"||pre[i].substring(b,b) == "N"||pre[i].substring(b,b) == "O")out[i] = out[i] + "6";
                if (pre[i].substring(b,b) == "7"||pre[i].substring(b,b) == "P"||pre[i].substring(b,b) == "Q"||pre[i].substring(b,b) == "R"||pre[i].substring(b,b)=="S")out[i] = out[i] + "7";
                if (pre[i].substring(b,b) == "8"||pre[i].substring(b,b) == "T"||pre[i].substring(b,b) == "U"||pre[i].substring(b,b) == "V")out[i] = out[i] + "8";
                if (pre[i].substring(b,b) == "9"||pre[i].substring(b,b) == "W"||pre[i].substring(b,b) == "X"||pre[i].substring(b,b) == "Y"||pre[i].substring(b,b)=="Z")out[i] = out[i] + "9";
                if (out[i].length() == 3 || out[i].length() == 7)out[i] = out[i]+ "-";
                if (b==12)System.out.println(out[i]);

            }
        }
    }

}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: 1  at
>   java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1951)  at
>   snowcalls1.SnowCalls1.main(SnowCalls1.java:30) Java Result: 1 BUILD
>   SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)

Right above is the output I get when I try to enter the number '1' as a input.

Comment: you should have a switch, and assign `pre[i].substring(b,b) to a variable and use that instead to improve readability

Comment: Also what problems are you having? why doesn't it work as you intended? Could you provide more details with what you're having trouble with?

Comment: and which line is line 24?

Comment: you're getting NPE because you haven't initialized `out`'s elements. So it will be `null`1

Comment: Thank you for the answer about the NPE output. I edited my post once again and now I get a different output? Sorry for troubling you but I just started learning the Java language.

Comment: Because there's a difference between index and length, length is one but the index for a one length array would be zero

Comment: Your logic is all wrong, try doing it the way i've done it in my answer

Comment: besides you're going to have `\n` as pre[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with these lines:

```
for (int i = 0;i<l;i++){
    pre[i] = input.nextLine();
}
```

What you're doing is entering a number into `System.in` such as 12345 then the above lines will read the next 12345 lines. I think what you want to do is break up the int `l` into it's component numbers.

Something like this:

```
String l = input.nextLine();
char pre [] = l.toCharArray();
```

There's some other logic errors in your code. Below you can see a working program for inputs 1,a,A,2,b and B:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
String l;
l = input.nextLine();
char pre [] = l.toCharArray();

String out = "";

for (int i = 0;i<l.length();i++){
    if (pre[i]== '1')
    {
        out = out + "1";
    }               
    if (pre[i] == '2'||Character.toUpperCase(pre[i])== 'A'|| Character.toUpperCase(pre[i]) == 'B')
    {
        out = out + "2";
    }
}
System.out.println(out);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. This definitely helped me very much. I will be sure to remember this logic for future references.